# How to stop Appium server using nodeJs in Java

Tags: java, appium

I am trying to start and stop Appium server programmatically.

I have nodeJS installed in my system.

For starting the server I am using "appium" command in a batch file and running that batch file using Java.

For stopping the server:

```
    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    runtime.exec("taskkill /F /IM node.exe");
```

But by using taskKill server is not killing.

Please suggest any methods by which I can stop the running Appium server.

Comment: I don't know appium. But proper servers have a documented shutdown routine (e.g. sending a signal, connecting on specific port, etc.). Maybe look for that in the documentation. But you already mentioned that it's nodejs software, so maybe it's too much to expect here. But keep in mind that killing a process might not terminate the software gracefully (writing unsaved data to disk etc.)

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways through which you can start & stop the appium server as,

1. With java methods by using start & stop server as,

```
  private AppiumDriver<?> driver;
  private AppiumDriverLocalService appiumDriverLocalService;
  private static final String NODE_FILE_PATH = "/usr/local/bin/node";
  private static final String APPIUM_FILE_PATH = "/usr/local/bin/appium";

  public void startAppiumServer() {
    Map<String, String> environment = new HashMap();
    environment.put("PATH", "/usr/local/bin:" + System.getenv("PATH"));
    AppiumServiceBuilder appiumServiceBuilder = new AppiumServiceBuilder();
    appiumServiceBuilder.usingAnyFreePort();
    appiumServiceBuilder.usingDriverExecutable(new File(NODE_FILE_PATH));
    appiumServiceBuilder.withAppiumJS(new File(APPIUM_FILE_PATH));
    appiumServiceBuilder.withEnvironment(environment);
    appiumDriverLocalService = AppiumDriverLocalService.buildService(appiumServiceBuilder);
    appiumDriverLocalService.start();
  }

  public void stopAppiumServer() {
    appiumDriverLocalService.stop();
  }
```

2. And, if you want to kill the appium server threads with shell command, you can use this as below,
   `sudo kill $(ps aux | grep -i appium | awk '{print $2}')`